# Best way to add marker with name on Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

What is the best way to add marker on Google map v2 with having name bottom of that marker? How to achieve it as like Google maps,is there any API for this? I tried it working fine but not in all devices perfectly.(showing marker name on top of the marker and on the marker in some devices).

```
// To put marker name and icon on the map
private Bitmap drawTitleOnMarkerIcon(MarkingInfo markingInfo, int color) {
    String title = markingInfo.getName();

    int icon = AddLocationTypeIcon.getIcon(markingInfo.getType());
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), icon).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    int bmHeight = bm.getHeight();

    int canvasWidth = bmWidth;
    int canvasHeight = bmHeight;
    if (bmWidth > 90) {
        canvasWidth = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), bmWidth - bmWidth/2);
        canvasHeight = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), bmHeight - bmHeight/2);
        bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, true);
    } else {
        canvasWidth = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), 72);
        canvasHeight = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), 72);
        bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, true);
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), paint.getTextSize()-3));

    float canvasCoorHeight = canvasHeight - paint.getTextSize()*2;// first y coordinate to start text from 
    while(title.length() > 0) {
        title = drawTextOnCanvas(paint, bm, title, canvasWidth, canvasCoorHeight);
        canvasCoorHeight = canvasCoorHeight + paint.getTextSize();// next text to draw at 12.5 + height
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i am expected:

```
// To show the map with existing user created markers
private void addExistingMarkers(int color) {
    userMarkers.clear();// remove all existing markers
    /**
     * Placing Marker
     * */
    List<MarkingInfo> markingInfos = SQLLiteManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .getAllAppMarkingInfos();

    for (MarkingInfo markingInfo : markingInfos) {

        // Set title on marker
        //Bitmap drawBmp = writeTextOnDrawable(markingInfo, color);
        Bitmap drawBmp = drawTitleOnMarkerIcon(markingInfo, color);


        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(markingInfo.getLattitude(), markingInfo.getLongtitutde()))
                .title(markingInfo.getName())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawBmp))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(drawBmp))
                // .anchor(0.5f, 1)
                .draggable(true)
                .visible(false);

        if (googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom >= markingInfo.getZoomlevel()) {
            markerOptions.visible(true);
        }

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        userMarkers.put(marker, markingInfo);
        marker.setDraggable(false);
    }
    Log.i("Existing markers", "Successfully placed existing markes on map ");
}

// To put marker name and icon on the map
private Bitmap drawTitleOnMarkerIcon(MarkingInfo markingInfo, int color) {
    String title = markingInfo.getName();

    int icon = AddLocationTypeIcon.getIcon(markingInfo.getType());
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), icon).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    int bmHeight = bm.getHeight();

    int canvasWidth = bmWidth;
    int canvasHeight = bmHeight;
    if (bmWidth > 90) {
        canvasWidth = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), bmWidth - bmWidth/2);
        canvasHeight = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), bmHeight - bmHeight/2);
        bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, true);
    } else {
        canvasWidth = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), 72);
        canvasHeight = (int)convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), 72);
        bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, true);
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(getApplicationContext(), paint.getTextSize()-3));

    float canvasCoorHeight = canvasHeight/2 + paint.getTextSize() + 6;// first y coordinate to start text from

    while(title.length() > 0) {
        title = drawTextOnCanvas(paint, bm, title, canvasWidth, canvasCoorHeight);
        canvasCoorHeight = canvasCoorHeight + paint.getTextSize();// next text to draw at 12.5 + height
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
    .title("Hello world"))
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
    .snippet("Your last recorded location")
```

mMap should be of type GoogleMap of course.

If you need anything additional just comment

Alternatively, you can set the icon image using the Marker.setIcon() method.

For more information, you can refer to this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: Thank you for quick reply,I want to add a marker with name dynamically I tried it i want to visible marker and name both at a time on map,not on info window after click on marker like this.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try using snippet() option along with a custome bitmap, and maybe Marker.setIcon method

Comment: Ok, I will try it for sure

Comment: I tried your answer this is what exactly i need. Thank you for your reply,but how can i set the length of the marker name on map and how to wrap it based on word length.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov can we insert image at title=image i mean on image title name comes on top of image  ex for xyz on image ......u have write a simple way of title if u know title assign in image can it dun............

Answer (score 1):

To achive what you want you will need to create some kind of method that will create your desired `Bitmap` form the `Marker` icon. this `Bitmap` will include you marker's icon with the text you want to present.

You can take a look at this guide to do that:

[Draw Text on Bitmap](http://www.skoumal.net/en/android-how-draw-text-bitmap)

Next as already been told, you will need to provide this `Bitmap` to the marker using the `.setIcon` method.

Comment: I tried your answer this is what exactly i need. Thank you for your reply,but how can i set the length of the marker name on map and how to wrap it based on word length.

Comment: I guess you will need to commit some kind of string manipulations, and wrap your text before you draw this text on the bitmap.

Comment: The name of the marker is showing on the marker in some mobiles(like micromax canvas hd) but when i tested in other mobiles like samsung galaxy grand and s2 showing correctly. why it(marker name) is jumping to top of the marker in some mobiles? what can i do get this name constant in all devices?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to do this, so I realy don't know. why won't ask a new question here regarding this?

Comment: Is there any way to add marker and name on map without using canvas? like Google maps can you please suggest me if you have any idea how they are doing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(youricon)
                .position(point)
                .title("Your location")
                .snippet("Your last recorded location")

        ).showInfoWindow();
```

The .showInfoWindow on the Marker will show the Title and Snippet text without user interaction.
You can hide it the same way.

Without .showInfoWindow it will only show the information when clicking it.